# why my crawledURL is null?

Tags: java, url, web, web-crawler

I am following a tutorial to create a web crawler in java. When I run the code my `crawledURL` is `null`. *** Malformed URL :null in a infinite loop.

Can anyone explain to me why is this happening?

Here is the whole code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class WebCrawler {

public static Queue<String> Queue = new LinkedList<>();
public static Set<String> marked = new HashSet<>();
public static String regex = "http[s]://(\\w+\\.)*(\\w+)";

public static void bfsAlgorithm(String root) throws IOException {

    Queue.add(root);

    while (!Queue.isEmpty()) {

        String crawledURL = Queue.poll();
        System.out.println("\n=== Site crawled : " + crawledURL + "===");

        //Limiting to a 100 websites here 

        if(marked.size() > 100)
            return;

        boolean ok = false;
        URL url = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        while (!ok) {
            try {
                url = new URL(crawledURL);
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                ok = true;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("*** Malformed URL :" + crawledURL);
                crawledURL = Queue.poll();
                ok = false;

            } catch (IOException ioe) { 
                System.out.println("*** IOException for URL :" + crawledURL);
                crawledURL = Queue.poll();
                ok = false;


        }

    }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((crawledURL = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(crawledURL);
        }

        crawledURL = sb.toString();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(crawledURL);


        while (matcher.find()){

            String w = matcher.group();

            if (!marked.contains(w)) {
                marked.add(w);
                System.out.println("Site added for crawling : " + w);
                Queue.add(w);
            }
        }

    }

}


public static void showResults() {
    System.out.println("\n\nResults :");
    System.out.print("Web sites craweled: " + marked.size() + "\n");

    for (String s : marked) {
        System.out.println("* " + s);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        bfsAlgorithm("http://www.ssaurel.com/blog");
        showResults();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        //TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll()

Comment: Thanks, but why my  queue is empty? On the tutorial is working

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!Queue.isEmpty()) {
    String crawledURL = Queue.poll();
...
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            crawledURL = Queue.poll();
```

second time you do not check is queue empty

Comment: Thanks . I am following exactely the tutorial and on the video everythihg is woking fine. Thats why I am trying to understand why U am catching this error.

Comment: I also prints `=== Site crawled : http://www.ssaurel.com/blog===` before going on the *** Malformed URL :null  loop-

Comment: For example, before first while() you had queue with 1 url, you extracted it and now have empty queue(). Below you got error for this url, retrieved next element from empty queue (null!) and tried to use it.

You need additional condition while(!ok && crawledUrl != null)

Comment: I dont understand why i have to do this when on the tutorial I am following everything is fine with the code. but thanks for trying to help me! Here is the tutorial.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyVjfz2Tuck

Comment: If it same code as in tutorial, then in tutorial just did not exists malformed or inacessible urls as last element of queue.

Comment: I can try another website to see if I get the same error

Comment: So, I tried to add  `!ok && crawledUrl != null` to the while loop and now I get this:

`*** IOException for  URL : http://www.ssaurel.com/blog`

before the crawledUrl was always returing null. What else should I look into?

Comment: just evaluate why url inacessble, add ioe.getMessage() to printing